# Dividers style does not work

Tags: android, android-layout

The code below is a layout that I am inflating to the main layout (attached on the root):

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.event_buttons, (ViewGroup) helperView, true );
setContentView(helperView);
```

However although having `style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"` the dividers are not displayed and they are transparent. There are "gaps" between the buttons but their color is transparent. If I configure the background of the linearlayout to a solid color, that color visible inside the gaps. Now it has a default background is `@null` as shown in the Graphical Layout.

```
<!-- This is my layout/event_buttons.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/eventDisplayButtons"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle"  // the style
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"  // this is not really necessary 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/open_link_button"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"  // child style
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white"
        android:drawablePadding="-2dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_menu_link"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:text="@string/open_link"
        android:textColor="@color/darkGrey"
        android:textSize="@dimen/event_buttons_text_size" />

    //two more buttons here

</LinearLayout>
```

I was thinking if my style/theme affects the dividers and they become transparent:

```
 <style name="MyTheme.TranslucentActionBar" /* the parent of MyTheme is android:Theme.Holo.Light */>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>


<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Assuming I have this theme how can solve this problem with the dividers?